# Is there any 3D modelling app in AS2 / AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, actionscript-2, modeling

I could not find any online app in flash that you can use to create models similar to http://www.3dtin.com/

I know that with 3d library Papervision3D you can do a lot, but to build an app 100% alone seems to be overwhelming.

It would be sufficient to have a tool to create simple shapes (cuboid, cone, pyramid). And the option to export it as PNG image.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For simple objects, i've have great success using ERain's Swift 3D.

http://www.erain.com/